# How to trigger ajax from a javascript graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Javascript noob. I have a forced directed graph from spring.js and I want to trigger ajax from it when the user selects a node but I keep getting an error 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .   this focusses on the line

```
function GetSpringyNode(node.data.label){
```

. I have managed to get it to trigger an alert but firing the ajax is tricky. Can anyone tell me how? I think the crux of the matter is how I pass the node.data.label to the ajax. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sebastiz/spnvf1q3/1/) and below is the code I am trying:

```
var graphJSON = <%=raw @users.to_json %>;
 var graph = new Springy.Graph();
 graph.loadJSON(graphJSON);
 var springy = jQuery('#springydemo').springy({graph: graph});


jQuery('#springydemo').springy({ graph: graph, nodeSelected: function(GetSpringyNode) {
    alert(node.data.label);
} });


                function GetSpringyNode(node.data.label){
                 $.ajax({
          url: "/users/show", 
          type: "GET", 
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {name: d.name},
          success: function(result) {
            //$('#NodeProfile').html(result);
            //$('.bchart-content').html(result);
            //Need to parse into html here before included in .bchart-content
            addGraph(result);
          }
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
jQuery('#springydemo').springy({ graph: graph, nodeSelected: function() {
    GetSpringyNode(node.data.label);
} });
```

and the GetSpringyNode function to this:

```
function GetSpringyNode(label){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/users/show", 
        type: "GET", 
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {name: label},
        success: function(result) {
        //$('#NodeProfile').html(result);
        //$('.bchart-content').html(result);
        //Need to parse into html here before included in .bchart-content
            addGraph(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain. It seems to work as long as I pass in nodeSelected: function(node) rather than function().... I guess the node dataset is passed as parameter and then the function GetSpringyNode is called with the label part of the node dataset. But i dont understand why then when starting the function, another parameter label is passed

Comment: I took your original code, and there the alert worked, so I assumed the node exists in that scope. The function nodeSelected is a callback that the springy will run when the node is selected. In your original code, the first parameter of that callback is called `GetSpringyNode` (which is not your function). When the callback runs, it will just set that parameter to the relevant value. The change I made was to make sure that your function will run when the node is selected.